# Exception Handling in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing a program for serial communications. To centralize the process of access to serial, created a class.

I am having problem when an exception is lançanda within the class leaves the locked program.

example:
When trying aberir the serial port, can give error and the system is at that point to burst memory.

How should I handle errors?
Put `try` and  `catch`? 
Add another routine?

#### Error point:

```
portSerial.Open();
```

#### Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PortSerial.Lib;

namespace ProgramPortSerial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form    {

        public static LibPortaSerial portSerial = new LibPortSerial();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            portSerial.LineReceived += new LineReceivedEventHandler(sp1_LineReceived);
            portSerial.Init(
                ref cmbPortas,
                ref cmbVelocidade,
                ref cmbBitsDeDados,
                ref cmbPariedade,
                ref cmbBitsDeParada,                
                ref cmbControleDeFluxo);            
        }

        void sp1_LineReceived(object sender, LineReceivedEventArgs Args)
        {
            // Tem que ser em uma nova thread para não travar
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                memDadosRecebidos.Text += "\r\n" + Args.Resposta;
            }));
        }

        private void btnAbrirPorta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            portSerial.Open();            
        }
    }
}
```

#### Class PortSerial

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PortSerial.Lib
{

    public class LibPortSerial : IDisposable
    {
        public SerialPort portSerial;        

        public LibPortSerial()
        {
            portSerial = new SerialPort();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (portSerial != null)
                portSerial.Dispose();
        }


        public void Open(
            string port, 
            int veloc,
            int bitsData,
            string pariedade,
            string bitsStop,
            string control)
        {
            portSerial.PortName = port;
            portSerial.BaudRate = veloc;
            portSerial.DataBits = bitsData;
            portSerial.Parity = SetPariedade(pariedade);
            portSerial.StopBits = SetBitsStop(bitsStop);
            portSerial.Handshake = Setcontrol(control); 
            portSerial.Open();  // ==>  Erro this point
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you want to handle the exception, put the try/catch in the calling client for the open method. You can also place try/catch in the called method to log results and raise another exception afterwards.

Comment: There is nothing to "handle" here.  You wrote a program for serial communications and you can't get the port opened.  That's the end of the show, there is no point in keeping the program running.  Just make sure that the user sees a good error message so he can do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should write it as:

```
public void Open(
        string port, 
        int veloc,
        int bitsData,
        string pariedade,
        string bitsStop,
        string control)
    {
        portSerial.PortName = port;
        portSerial.BaudRate = veloc;
        portSerial.DataBits = bitsData;
        portSerial.Parity = SetPariedade(pariedade);
        portSerial.StopBits = SetBitsStop(bitsStop);
        portSerial.Handshake = Setcontrol(control); 
      try
        {
            portSerial.Open();  // ==>  Erro this point
        }

      catch(IOException exp)
            {
                return exp.Message;
            }
    }
```